# If I've Downloaded JDK, Do I Need to Download Eclipse Too?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm pretty new to programming and to Java, so I'm really not sure.
I know that JDK has its own compiler and the JRE too so would I really need Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the JRE to run java code on your computer and the JDK to write it. However, many programmers tend to prefer an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) to use along side for actually writing the code, debugging, and execute it much more efficiently. Eclipse is a good example of one, and one of the many used/preferred IDE's (in my opinion at least) out there. However, others exist too:

- DrJava
- Netbeans
- BlueJ
- JCreator

These editors are much more preferred because they make it easier to learn / write code. However, you may choose a normal text editor (like sublime, atom, textedit, notepad, textmate, etc..) or even the command line. Mac & Linux have "vim" built in which is a command line editor too which I tend to prefer.

Comment: *the JDK & JRE are both required to program in java locally on your computer* incorrect. You only need the JRE to run Java programs. JDK is to write them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the JDK and JRE are necessary to run java but Eclipse is the tool that will allow you to code, debug and execute easier.

Think of JDK as the engine of a car and Eclipse or any other IDE like the wheel.

Comment: I would say that the IDEs are the tools to build the rest of the car rather than wheels.